# Multi threading processing Problem

Tags: vb.net

I just learned some basics of multi threading in VB.net recently as I came across processing a large List of records and inserting them into SQL database one by one. 
I have code look like this:

```
  Private Sub btnLoadNow_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLoadNow.Click

    Dim autoLoad1 As New Thread(AddressOf AutoLoad)
    autoLoad1.Start()

    Dim autoLoad2 As New Thread(AddressOf AutoLoad)
    autoLoad2.Start()

    Dim autoLoad3 As New Thread(AddressOf AutoLoad)
    autoLoad3.Start()

    Dim autoLoad4 As New Thread(AddressOf AutoLoad)
    autoLoad4.Start()

    Dim autoLoad5 As New Thread(AddressOf AutoLoad)
    autoLoad5.Start()


    Dim autoLoad6 As New Thread(AddressOf AutoLoad)
    autoLoad6.Start()

    Dim autoLoad7 As New Thread(AddressOf AutoLoad)
    autoLoad7.Start()

    Dim autoLoad8 As New Thread(AddressOf AutoLoad)
    autoLoad8.Start()

    Dim autoLoad9 As New Thread(AddressOf AutoLoad)
    autoLoad9.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub AutoLoad()

for each Item as Record In ItemLists
   Process Codes
Next

End Sub
```

Itemlists is a global lists i retrieved from database, everything looks fine to me but when i run this program, I found that the threads are inserting one records 9 times into the database(I have 9 threads in total), which makes me think that maybe i need to specifically assign 1/9 of a list to each thread? Is there another way to do it which doesn't require the splitting of the list, if not , how do i split it then assign? any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't make one thread per insert as the overhead of creating the thread outweighs the benefits you'd get from spinning it in the first place.  However, you could use a shared variable and use SyncLock to maintain concurrency.

Edit to Comment Question:

```
'Replace List(Of String) with your type.
Public Shared ItemList As New List(Of String)
```

This is usually used for updates on memory in contention.  Your first thread would end up always doing all of the processing in your example.  If you really wanted to spin a couple of threads and split up the work, assign each thread a name and then have your procedure hold the logic to assign different work to each thread.

Comment: I do have synclock inside looping code. Do you mind show me an example of using a shared variable please? thanks.